# Multiple Ajax.BeginForm in one page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on an MVC .NET project, i have multiple file uploaders in a single page, each of them have a job to do,my question is that is it normal to have mutiple Ajax.BeginForm in a single page for each uploader?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Upload", options, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="uploadTLMFilesForm">
                    <h2>KPI 1</h2>
                    <p>SKU Age Upon Loading &amp; Arrival</p>
                    <input id="uploadFiles" type="file" name="files" class="files-uploader" accept=".csv, text/csv"  multiple />
                    <hr class="uploadButtonSeperator" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="uploadButton" />  
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FileUpload2", "Upload", options, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
...
}
```

Comment: yes you can have but with multiple ids. An also remember to have triggering buttons inside the form.

Comment: According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element) said. It is normal.